How to implement Auto log off based on user interactivity in AvaloniaUI
I'm building an AvaloniaUI app and would like to auto log off users after the app is idle for a period of time. I've found a great solution to this for WPF here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42884/Implementation-of-Auto-Logoff-Based-on-User-Inacti
but this doesn't port to Avalonia. It involves the following code which goes in the code-behind of the MainWindow:
private void InitializeAutoLogoffFeature()
        {
            HwndSource windowSpecificOSMessageListener = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
            windowSpecificOSMessageListener.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(CallBackMethod));
            AutoLogOff.LogOffTime = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogOffIdleMinutes"]);
            AutoLogOff.MakeAutoLogOffEvent += new AutoLogOff.MakeAutoLogOff(AutoLogOff_MakeAutoLogOffEvent);
            AutoLogOff.StartAutoLogoffOption();
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            //tblStatus.Text = "Timer is started at " + ": " + time;
        }
        private IntPtr CallBackMethod(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            //  Listening OS message to test whether it is a user activity
            if ((msg >= 0x0200 && msg <= 0x020A) || (msg <= 0x0106 && msg >= 0x00A0) || msg == 0x0021)
            {
                AutoLogOff.ResetLogoffTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

The stuff in the "AutoLogOff" class looks easy to reproduce. The parts that I don't know how to reproduce are mainly just the following two lines and the IntPtr CallBackMethod:
HwndSource windowSpecificOSMessageListener = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
windowSpecificOSMessageListener.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(CallBackMethod));


 //  Listening OS message to test whether it is a user activity
 if ((msg >= 0x0200 && msg <= 0x020A) || (msg <= 0x0106 && msg >= 0x00A0) || msg == 0x0021)
  {
       AutoLogOff.ResetLogoffTimer();
  }

Right now my app is just intended to target Windows Desktop, however if there's a general way of doing it so it works in WebAssembly, MAUI and MacOS that'd be great.
Thanks!
